# jQuery Final Countdown plugin get date from span element

Tags: jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

I working on a auction page with multiple instances of countdown dates. I'm using [The Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) jQuery plugin. For multiple instances, it gets the date value from the [data-countdown] attribute. Example below.

```
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/01/01"></div>
```

What I want though is to get the date value from within the element itself like the follow.

```
<div class="time-and-date">2016/01/01</div>
```

This is JS I have so far.

```
$('time-and-date').text().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data({.text()});
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
   });
});
```

I have a fiddle set up.

http://jsfiddle.net/Covanant/gNbRL/

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind trying to pull the date from the text? could help us create a better solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the value of your `finalDate` to `finalDate = $(this).text()`

```
$('.time-and-date').each(function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    var finalDate;

    if($that.attr('data-countdown')) finalDate = $that.data('countdown');
    else finalDate = $that.text();

    $that.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
        $that.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNbRL/2/)

Comment: Thanks I knew it had something to do with .text. Just couldn't figure out where to place it.

Comment: @Chozen not a problem. If it is a sufficient answer, please mark it as such.